Can you call the method of a parent class in a way that it references a subclass with the same name as a class it depends on?
I have a Game that references classes HouseRules, Card, and Player. I'd like to add functionality to each class.
I've made a subclass called Game and subclasses called HouseRules, Card, and Player that have new methods and attributes in addition to those of their corresponding parents. I'd like the unchanged methods to still function as expected, except that they refer to the updated forms of each class. Below is my minimal reproducible example with just one class (subclass) that depends on one class (subclass).
I've created a class Foo that takes in its initialization an object of class Obj. If no object is given, it's set to a default Obj().
'src.py'
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=1): 
        self.a = a 
        self.b = b

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        self.obj=Obj() if obj is None else obj
        ...

I'd like to build on Foo's functionality in a new project, so I've made a new file and subclassed src.Foo.
This new Foo's functionalities will need a slightly more complicated Obj that has an attribute z, so I made a subclass of src.Obj.
'main.py'
import src
class Obj(src.Obj):
    def __init__(self, z=0, **kwargs):
        self.z = z
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Foo(src.Foo):
    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        #self.obj=Obj() if obj is None else obj
        super().__init__(obj)

Originally I didn't include the commented line. I thought that if obj was passed as None, super().__init__(obj) would turn obj into the new improved Obj().
But it became the old Obj() and threw an error when I tried to access its nonexistent attribute z.
So, I added the line and this fixes it.

Another idea is to replace
'src.py'
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        self.obj=Obj() if obj is None else obj

with
'src.py'
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        self.obj=self.default_obj if obj is None else obj

    @property
    def default_obj(self): return Obj()

Then copy the getter and paste it in Foo in 'main.py', where it will return the Obj() from 'main.py'.

A third idea is to make Obj a nested class and set self.obj to self.Obj().
'src.py'
class Foo:
    class Obj:
        def __init__(self, a=1, b=1): 
            ...

    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        self.obj=self.Obj() if obj is None else obj
        ...

'main.py'
import src
class Foo(src.Foo):
    class Obj(src.Foo.Obj):
        def __init__(self, z=0, **kwargs):
            ...

    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        super().__init__(obj)

I've heard nested classes are generally to be avoided. Also, I noticed I couldn't use super().Obj, I had to type src.Foo.Obj, which means if I change the name of the superclass or something, I'd have to be sure to change it in two places.
But my question is: in the interest of avoiding repeating the obj-assigning line (or alternatively repeating the getter or the class inheritance, or having src.py import main), is there any way to call the parent class's initialization that will turn obj into the Obj() in 'main.py' instead of 'src.py'?
Although it would only be repetition of one simple line (or getter) in this minimal case, I actually have three updated subclasses. To use these techniques I've considered would mean copying all superclass methods that create instances of these subclasses verbatim into the subclass so that they refer to the new subclasses, which diminishes the benefits of using inheritance.
If there's a better practice for achieving what I'm attempting than subclassing each class of a project, feel free to let me know.

I'm not sure why you want two sets of classes with the same names.  Before getting into the details of Python's inheritance, I would start at the top by explaining what you're trying to achieve.  Then sketch out a possible design, using meaningful class names (and without duplicate names).

For example, a common scenario would be a Game abstract base class, then subclasses e.g. PokerGame and BlackjackGame.  You might also have e.g. a PokerHouseRules class (either a base class or a subclass of HouseRules) and a LakesideCasinoPokerHouseRules that is subclass of PokerHouseRules (with other subclasses for each supported casino).

I would also recommend reading about design patterns and object-oriented principles, e.g. the strategy pattern and dependency injection.  If e.g. PokerGame depends on PokerHouseRules, you should always pass an instance of PokerHouseRules (meaning an instance of a concrete subclass) to the constructor of PokerGame.  This is better than having PokerGame construct an instance of PokerHouseRules (as you do with Foo and Obj).

Game (uno.py) is made to run in the console; the user sees cards printed in ASCII and enters inputs. Game (uno_gui.py) is made to run in its own window; the user sees card images and clicks on tthem.The gui Game has additional functions, but many repeated functions. I wanted to be able to edit how those functions work in one place, and they'd be carried to the updated Game without copying and pasting them. To follow your suggestion I could append GUI to each new version of the class.

"you should always pass an instance of PokerHouseRules" are you saying I shouldn't set default values for my classes e.g. Game(houseRules=HouseRules_GUI(), deck=...), I should make it a required parameter e.g. Game(houseRules, deck, ...)?

I think I've got it. Right now I have a function Game().run() at the bottom of all my defined classes that runs the code. Just before that line I should put houseRules=HouseRules_GUI(); deck=...; then instead put Game(houseRules,deck,...).run(). So I still set default values for these but not in Game(), I set them before I instantiate Game() and pass them in. But I'm still a little lost. I like the idea of thinking of houseRules as optional, and the game stores default rules in case you don't provide any. Why is it worse to construct an instance of the object inside Game?

"Why is it worse to construct an instance of the object inside Game?"  I recommend you read up on dependency injection (DI).  In short, DI helps classes do one specific thing, while staying flexible about how other classes do their job.  Having Game construct a default muddies the waters a little on who decides the house rules (Game or its caller).  However, you can still use DI even with a default.

I would work to architect your app so you have two UIs (e.g. UnoConsoleApp and UnoGUIApp), but the core classes (e.g. HouseRules, Card, etc.) are used unchanged by both apps.  The key is Separation of Concerns.  HouseRules needs to know for example what moves are legal in each situation.  Card needs to represent the data (e.g. number or type (e.g. Reverse)) of an UNO card, not the appearance of a card or how it's displayed on screen.  UI classes will accept e.g UNOGameState, display information, and accept user input.  This is a great learning opportunity!  Keep it up!

First thigns first - don't do nested classes.  :-)
So - a simple way to do that, is to have the base-associated classes you rely on as class attributes in the base Foo, (or Game) -  and retrieve that attribute to instantiate each class. Then, in the subclass of Foo (Game), simply override those attributes.
No need to mess around with properties or whatever:
# src.py

class Obj:
    ...

class Foo:
    # This binds this class.Obj to the "Obj" visible in
    # the global scope
    Obj = Obj
    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        self.obj=self.Obj() if obj is None else obj
        
...
# other.py
import src
class Obj(src.Obj):
    # add extra stuff and overrides as desired!
    ...

class Foo(src.Foo):
    # Binds the class Obj attribute to the Obj visible here!
    Obj = Obj
    
    # Just with that, if nothing changes in __init__
    # you don't even need to redeclare it and call super()...:
    # the original Foo.__init__ will take care of
    # instantianting the derived Obj visible here!
    


Okay, thanks for reading! So I'd add HouseRules=HouseRules; Card=Card; Player=Player; at the beginning inside both "Game"s. Then edit the methods that refer to each class in the original Game to refer to self.class instead.
